Is "swabbed in dirty robes" a valid expression?
I have been recently playing a horror video game "Lost in Vivo" by Akuma Kira. In locations of this game there are a handful of notes and memos the player can read, and in one of them I met this peculiar expression of "swabbed in dirty robes", which implies that "swab" may have a meaning akin to "clothed", "dressed".

A dark creature swabbed in dirty robes now lives within them.

However, Oxford Languages gives only two definitions of the verb "swab", none of which fits to the passage in the letter:

1.take a specimen of tissue or secretions from (a person or part of the body) for examination. 
2. clean (a floor or other surface) with a mop or other absorbent device.


So I am now puzzled, whether the expression in the game is erroneous.

Shocking, an error in a video game!

Maybe a mistake for 'swaddled'.

@NigelJ - isn't that just infants?

@MichaelHarvey 2. To wrap round with bandages; to envelop with wrappings; to swathe, bandage. Also with up. OED

@NigelJ - I bow to the OED, but note the last quote in my 2nd Ed (1989) is from 1897, but we are talking about 'poetry' of a kind, so OK.

I mean; dirty robes can make good cleaning rags but only to a point.

I'm guessing that the intended word was "swathed", which (in my idiolect, at least) rhymes with "swabbed".

to bind, wrap, or swaddle with or as if with a bandage


Yep. The more traditional sound change might be d (e.g., the formation of swaddle), but I could imagine someone hearing it and thinking it was a -bbed.

I searched Google for "swabbed in * robes" but the only 2 hits relate to this game. I found one instance of "swabbed in swaddling clothes" (repeated a few places) but again it's seemingly a mistake. Other mentions of "swabbed ... clothes" are about security services at airports taking swabs from them.

@StuartF ("Swabbed in swabbling clothes"?)

I feel like swab is used figuratively and it is legit. Perhaps, an uncommon and kind of 'forced' usage, to evoke a more grimy connotation. I've googled and found "swabbed in furs" and other figurative usages as well. However, this can stay as the accepted answer, I don't mind.

To me, it rhymes with bathed.

@ermanen Swabbing implies a type of brushing or rubbing motion. I might say something could be "swabbed in disinfectant" since disinfectant could be applied with a swab. But I think "swabbed in furs" is just an error, there is no sense of a swabbing action whatsoever. I don't see how you can swab something (as a verb) without having an object that could be even remotely be considered a swab (as a noun) - swabbing requires a swab.

@NuclearHoagie Yes, hence I said uncommon and 'forced' connotation, similar to how 'soak' can be used figuratively but less obvious. It needs further explanation, I didn't post an answer. Not simple as comparing to the usual meaning of 'swab". It is more of a creative usage. And this answer can be correct also.

@KateBunting That's why I referred to my idiolect - apparently a lot of people agree with you. Not sure where I acquired my pronunciation.

Swathed definitely here, perhaps you could say 'swabbed (meaning smeared) with dirty rags' but that is far from clothing someone (even a demon spawn).

@KateBunting: I assume you mean "bathed" as in "to bathe", rather than "bathed" as in "to bath" :)

@psmears - Yes.

It is possible to swab someone with clothes (e.g. as a means to wipe sweat or other fluids off when a towel is not available). But that's clearly not the intent here and this is the correct answer.
